# How can we compute cube-root in python with specified precision?

Tags: python, python-2.6

How can we compute cube-root in python with specified precision?

I would like to use the decimal class for this and my compiler is python 2.5

I tried using something like this:

```
  >>> from decimal import *
  >>> x=Decimal("10")
  >>> print x**(Decimal("1.0")/3)

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
      print x**(Decimal("1.0")/3)
   File "C:\Python25\lib\decimal.py", line 1752, in __pow__
      return context._raise_error(InvalidOperation, 'x ** (non-integer)')
   File "C:\Python25\lib\decimal.py", line 2325, in _raise_error
      raise error, explanation
   InvalidOperation: x ** (non-integer)
 >>>
```

That's working on Python 2.6 and onwards but not in Python 2.5? Any solution for that?

Comment: The parameter to your function is `n` but should probably be `x`

Comment: works on `Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin`

Comment: Yes I already mentioned that but not working in pyth 2.5.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely works in 2.5.2, maybe there was a change since 2.5?

```
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jan 20 2010, 21:48:48) 
[GCC 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> x=Decimal("10")
>>> x**(Decimal("1.0")/3)
Decimal('2.154434690031883721759293566')
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the release notes at http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.5/NEWS.txt , there were quite a few bug fixes/updates to the decimal module in 2.5.2. If you are using 2.5.0 or 2.5.1, can you upgraded to 2.5.2?